# PHP - date formatting issue

Tags: php

I am trying to format dates from a UK format to YYYY-MM-DD an am getting weird results.

The code I am using is:

```
echo "<br>".$_GET['trans_date'];
echo "<br>".$_GET['next_payment'];
echo "<br>".$_GET['payment_date'];
echo "<br><br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['trans_date']));
echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['next_payment']));
echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['payment_date']));
```

And I get the following results:

```
19/05/2016
01/06/2016
19/05/2016

1970-01-01
2016-01-06
1970-01-01
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
19/05/2016
01/06/2016
19/05/2016

2016-05-19
2016-01-01
2016-05-19
```

Can anyone what's going wrong?

Thanks,

John

Comment: As per the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php): when PHP encounters a `/` in a date with a `xx/xx/xxxx` structure, it treats it as US format (`mm/dd/yyyy`).... either change the `/` to `-` before using `strtotime()` or use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a DateTime object

Comment: strtotime function expects to be given a string containing an English date format ( mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
echo "<br><br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['trans_date'])));
echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['next_payment'])));
echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_GET['payment_date'])));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really set a locale for strtotime.

If you're American, you see 11/12/10 and think "12th November, 2010".

If you're Australian (or European), you think it's "11th December, 2010".

If you're a sysadmin who reads in ISO, it looks like "10th December 2011".

The best way to compensate for this is by modifying your joining characters.

Forward slash (/) signifies American M/D/Y formatting, 
a dash (-) signifies European D-M-Y and 
a period (.) signifies ISO Y.M.D.

So, My suggestion is always use DateTime object for dates to avoid unnecessary errors.

```
Ex: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Coming to your question, solution is:

```
$trans_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['trans_date']);
$next_payment_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['next_payment']);
$payment_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_GET['payment_date']);

echo "<br><br>".$trans_date->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br>".$next_payment_date->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br>".$payment_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Set you given date to `05/19/2016` means `mm/dd/yy` format and it will be fixed.